# JQuery submit Via Ajax doesnt work

Tags: jquery, ajax

submit button

```
<td><span id="harvest-submit" class="save-floppy fa fa-floppy-o"></i></span></td>
```

jquery code

```
$('#harvest-submit').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/smartfarm/control/saveHarvestGrade',
            type:'POST',
            data:$('#createHarvestGrades').serialize(),
            success:function(result){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "/smartfarm/control/ajaxHarvestGradeList",
                type: "POST",
                data: {cropId:$('.harvest-grade-disable').attr("val")},
                success: function(data) {
                            $('.harvest-grade-list').html(data);
                            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#grade-list-last-line").offset().top}, 2000);
                            $('.info-box-hg').html('Created Successfully!!')
                            $('.info-box-hg').show();
                            setTimeout(function() { $(".info-box-hg").hide(); }, 5000);
                            $('.warning-box-hg').hide();
                            $('.alert-box-hg').hide();
                }
            });
          }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesnt work" ? Any clues?

Comment: what is going wrong give some more details

Comment: Your tags are not nested correctly

Comment: did you check that with console in chrome/firefox

Comment: check  your Console it gives any error ??

Comment: im trying to submit and save the data using jquery but submit button is not clicking or saving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon after the "Created Successfully!!" line in the last ajax success call.  You also aren't handling errors so if you get an ajax error the other branches of the code will not be reached and may fail silently.

Comment: Have you added the other event handling in the ajax call?  Your code my be fine client side and is failing on the server-side.  Without the other events being handled you my have trouble debugging.  If you misspelled the resource you are requesting you may be returning a 404, or if there is a server-side programming problem you may be getting an error 500.  You will not know this unless you handle the other events.  You may want to dump the output of the error and/or the complete event instead of just expecting the success event which isn't always triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I put your code into $(document).ready(function(){ }); and it will run (with button instead of span). Where do you have this code in your page?You have to take the right pace to add the click event.

Comment: Works fine with spans too the tag nesting was incorrect.  http://jsfiddle.net/LkxL87qL/1/

Answer (score 0):

i think have some wrong tag in your

```
<td><span id="harvest-submit" class="save-floppy fa fa-floppy-o"></i></span></td>,
```

you put **i** close tag, where its opening that?, that might not be he issue, but you should check that or if its working for you, can you put some alert that you can ensure the call get into that function

or you can call like this

```
$("#harvest-submit").live("click", function(){});
```